# How do I replace one argument in each formula in a column of formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, find-and-replace

I have a column of formulas like this:

```
=VLOOKUP($C3,Sheet4!$A$1:$H$50,7,0)
```

picking up the details in column 7, as you can see.  But I have now removed two columns from sheet 4 and the pertinent information is in column 5, so how do I find and replace all the cells with the above formula with

```
=VLOOKUP($C3,Sheet4!$A$1:$H$50,5,0)
```

in one fell swoop?!

Oh, I forgot to say, the first reference, `$C3`, changes in each formula! Sorry! So, for example, in the next cell down it might be `$C16`. That really puts a spanner in the works, huh?

Comment: [find and replace](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Find-or-replace-text-and-numbers-on-a-worksheet-3a2c910f-01b9-4263-8db2-333dead6ae33?CorrelationId=66ef5645-a06b-4905-905c-508f1c69e43f&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: To answer your actual question, it's Find and Replace as others have answered. However, it's for this exact reason that you should avoid `VLOOKUP` if possible.  http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/why-index-match-is-better-than-vlookup/

Comment: I LOVE YOU! I never knew about this and have just tried one of them and it works perfectly. I don't have to fear now in case I have to add a couple more columns in later on in the year. So, now can you please tell me how I could replace all my vlookups with indexmatch? Bearing in mind that my lookups are all different, referring to arrays in different sheets, etc. I can post my ss to you if you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Excel's Find-and-replace feature to do this. Just select the column with the formulas and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the Replace dialog.

Search for:

```
Sheet4!$A$1:$H$50,7,0)
```

Replace with:

```
Sheet4!$A$1:$H$50,5,0)
```

Just be careful that you don't have any formulas in the selection that include the search string but you don't want to change.

Comment: Hi, except that will only work for one. As I said, the next formula will not have $A$1, but will perhaps have $A$23, so the find and replace that you suggested will not work. Sorry.

Comment: Oh, I thought only the formulas only differed in the first argument, as you specified in the question. The same idea applies though. Check the formulas to see if `:$H$50,7,0)` would work, and barring that, `,7,0)`.